# Change the alignment of the staircase in R

Tags: r, paste, cat

I am trying to make staircase of given length *n* using the following function:

```
hash<-function(n){
  for (i in 1:n){
    v1=c()
    #j=1
    for (j in 1:i){
      v1=paste("#",v1,sep="")
    }
    cat(v1,"\n")
  }
}
```

But I want it right aligned. What I am getting is:

```
 # 
 ## 
 ### 
 #### 
 ##### 
 ######
```

I was wondering, can I get some help how to make it aligned the other way?thanks for the assistance.

Comment: That looks similar to what I thought.

Comment: @rawr Thanks a lot.

Comment: @akrun undelete your answer

Comment: @rawr Your answer is more compact and useful.  I unnecessarily collapsed with `paste`.  Please post that as answer.  After all, you commented before my answer.

Comment: I was wondering which package do I need to use  _strrep_ function. Right now, I am getting the message;                                                                 **error: could not find function strrep.** thanks

Comment: Please check your R version, I think it was introduced in R 3.3.0 or greater.  BTW, this is rawr's deleted solution `cat(format(strrep('#', 1:6), width = 6, justify = 'r'), sep = '\n')`

Answer (score 0):

```
n=6
for (i in 1:n) {
  v1=c()
  v2=c()
  for (j in i:n-1) {
     v1=paste(" ",v1,sep="")
  }
  for (k in i:1) {
     v2=paste("#",v2,sep="")
  }
  cat(v1,v2,"\n")
}
```

Comment: Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Comments would help create searchable content.