# Function in R to arrange coins in staircase.Task is to determine the number of complete rows of coins in the finished staircase

Tags: r

Coins arrangement Example-
If there are 6 coins then a staircase with 1 coin in the top row, 2 in the second row & 3 in the third row.So, in total 3 rows can be completed.To complete the 4th row, 4 more coins would be required i.e. in total 10 coins.

**Each row should have exactly one coin more than the row above it.**

I have to generate a function that arranges the coin such that, for each coins [k] function must print an integer denoting the max. no of complete rows that can be created.
Arranging coin has the following conditions-
1.coins[coins[0], -------coins[m-1] an array of long integers each representing the number of coins
2. m is in the range of 1 to 10^5.
3.coins[k] is in the range between 1 to 10^15.

Comment: What have you tried thus far?

Comment: I referred -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40962641/change-the-alignment-of-the-staircase-in-r.  But, I couldn't find the maximum no. of complete rows that can be created.

Comment: I did it in python-for i in range(input()):
    K = input()
    print (K/2)*(K/2)+(K/2)*(K%2). Need this to be implemented in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function below starts with index = 1 and keeps a running sum of the index values in sumval. It stops when sumval is greater than k and returns the index-1. This corresponds to the number of steps.

```
steps <- function(k) {
    index <- 1
    sumval <- 1
    while (sumval <= k) {
        index <- index + 1
        sumval <- sumval + index
    }
    return(index-1)
}
```

The function took about 3.0 seconds to calculate the value for k=1e15 (44721359) on my mid-2013 MacBook Air (MacBookAir6,2).